# How to override oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.WorkflowDefinitionMaxLength property while submitting the oozie job

Tags: cloudera, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have an application which dynamically generates oozie workflow.xml and now the size is increased to 245,524 bytes which is exceeding the default limit of 100000 bytes and getting the below error while running the job:

Error: E0736 : E0736: Workflow definition length [245,524] exceeded maximum allowed length [100,000]

This property can be set in oozie-default.xml but I would like to set in the application level. Is there any other way to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property can't be set on an application level, only in oozie-site.xml. Setting it requires an Oozie restart.

Have you considered breaking down your huge xml to many smaller pieces using the [subworkflow action?](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.5_Sub-workflow_Action) It might help you reduce some duplication as well if you use parameters in the subworkflows.